# How make YouTube videos support full screen via WebView

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I'm having an immense difficulty to make my WebView support YouTube videos in full screen.

Below you can see my code, without any support for YouTube full screen.

```
package br.com.joguindie.joguindiesocial;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView  mWebView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);       
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://social.joguindie.com.br");


    }

       public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /** Show a toast from the web page */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

I hope someone can help me! Thank you very much!